# How can I break a list in an array into separated elements?

Tags: arrays, list, scipy

I had to make a matix with scipy code coo_matrix which is supposed to have 34*34 size and later I should use each float elements for calculation.

```
K =coo_matrix((keelement,(iK,jK)),shape=(Nnodes*ndofs,Nnodes*ndofs)).todense()
```

but when I try to use K[i][j] then occurs an index error. I checked the matrix with print and realized that it's not 34*34 array but 34*1, as each rows are entirely bound into one list.

```
[[ 46827079.33815667 -10240619.007235   -40000000.         ...,         0.
      0.                 0.        ]
[-10240619.007235    42027595.17751917         0.         ...,         0.
      0.                 0.        ]
[-40000000.                 0.          86827079.33815667 ...,         0.
      0.                 0.        ]
..., 
[        0.                 0.                 0.         ...,
42027595.17751917         0.                 0.        ]
[        0.                 0.                 0.         ...,         0.
46827079.33815667 -10240619.007235  ]
[        0.                 0.                 0.         ...,         0.
-10240619.007235    42027595.17751917]]
```

As you can see, I can't use the numbers individually because the whole 'row' is considered as just one element, as if it's a list of string. I can't understand why it's happening because I have another code using same matrix made by coo_matrix and that code works just fine.

Please let me know what I'm missing or what I had to search for.

Comment: Try doing `K[i, j]` instead. scipy sparse matrices, when densified, return numpy `Matrix` objects, which stay 2D for most operations.

Comment: Thanks, that worked right! Yet still I can't figure out why K[i][j] is wrong and K[i,j]is right

Comment: `K[i]` returns a 2D array (more precisely a `matrix` object) of shape `(1, cols)`, not a 1D array of shape `(cols,)`, so the second indexing operation is being applied again over the rows, only there is only one, hence the index error.